# How to wire up a RJ45 socket with cat-5 cable?

Tags: networking

I have some network cable laid, but no sockets as yet. I have done a quick google, and have not had much luck with explanations (other than on the hyphen site).

Is there a good, comprehensive guide to how to wire up Ethernet sockets, any advice would also be greatly appreciated as it sounds like a bit of a nightmare.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wiring up an Ethernet socket is very similar to wiring up a cable itself, the order of the wires is the same, the method of wiring them is slightly different, dependent on your socket.

The image below shows the 2 standard configurations for cat 5(and 6). A crossover cable (for directly connecting 2 PC's) would have one end of type A and on of type B, a normal straight through cable, from switch to PC, would have both the same type. You need to ensure that all your cables use the same type through out, either A or B.

[image: Network Cable Layout]

Once decided, you would wire up your sockets in the same order as you would your cables. Most sockets have markers indicating which PIN number goes where, so just make sure you follow the order in your chosen layout and they will work fine.

Comment: in case of peer-to-peer connection you'd need to swap the connectors either of the side.

Comment: As stated - "A crossover cable (for directly connecting 2 PC's) would have one end of type A and on of type B"

Comment: For T568A vs. T568B, the comment "use same type of cables through out" is misleading. Everything will work fine as long each connection uses the same standard at both ends of the same cable. For example, there is nothing "incompatible" about using a T568A patch cord with a T568B infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Wikipedia page about [Category 5 cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable).

The picture there shows nicely how to connect it. Make sure you have the same standard (A or B) at both ends. :-)

Answer (score 2):

How much is "some" cable?

If it's for a company, the time spent learning and making mistakes can more than pay for an hour or two of a professional's time.

I wired up a few network drops in my day (10 base T anyone?).  I'm still amazed when a true pro comes in and can punch and test 48 connections in a half day.  It's neat and tidy.  Now when our network guys start running patch cables... THAT gets messy, but they had a clean slate to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to get sockets with punch blocks that are specified to the gauge of the cable you have laid, or else you will ruin the punch blocks. Using the tool, not a screwdriver, push the wires into the punch blocks according to the scheme like Sam Cogan described. It is easy if you have the correct tool and cable gauge, but frustratingly difficult if not.